# AWS Kinesis - Empty record in lambda

Tags: lambda, aws-lambda, amazon-kinesis

I have the following setup:

```
API Gateway > Kinesis > Lambda
```

The API Gateway is being called but the data coming through to the Lambda function is empty.

```
exports.handler = (event, context, callback) => {
    event.Records.forEach((record) => {
        console.log('record', record);
    }
}
```

I get an output of...

```
{ kinesisSchemaVersion: '1.0',
partitionKey: 'some-partition-key',
sequenceNumber: '49572842939259722444903461552052718872116185957331369986',
data: 'e30=',
approximateArrivalTimestamp: 1494948079.296 },
eventSource: 'aws:kinesis',
eventVersion: '1.0',
eventID: 'shardId-000000000000:49572842939259722444903461552052718872116185957331369986',
eventName: 'aws:kinesis:record',
invokeIdentityArn: 'arn:aws:iam::************:role/service-role/basic-lambda-execute-role',
awsRegion: 'eu-west-1',
eventSourceARN: 'arn:aws:kinesis:eu-west-1:************:stream/sensor-readings' }
```

The point of interest there is `data: 'e30='`

The results are the same if I invoke the endpoint from the APIG Method Test form.  It shows the following response which to me looks all good.

```
Execution log for request test-request
Wed May 17 08:36:45 UTC 2017 : Starting execution for request: test-invoke-request
Wed May 17 08:36:45 UTC 2017 : HTTP Method: POST, Resource Path: /reading
Wed May 17 08:36:45 UTC 2017 : Method request path: {}
Wed May 17 08:36:45 UTC 2017 : Method request query string: {}
Wed May 17 08:36:45 UTC 2017 : Method request headers: {}
Wed May 17 08:36:45 UTC 2017 : Method request body before transformations: {
  "version" : "0.01",
  "concentrator": {
    "id": "con123",
    "rssi": -87,
    "snr": 10.1,
    "gwid": "Gateway1"
  },
  "client": {
    "name": "LukesTestDB",
    "site": "TheSite"
  },
  "data": [
    {
      "timestamp": "1486124533248000000",
      "ch0": "10",
      "ch1": "34",
      "ch2": "56",
      "ch3": "78"
    }
  ],
  "device": {
    "id": "DEV_789",
    "rssi": "100",
    "chx": "ch0",
    "asset": "MyAsset",
    "bType": "MyBType",
    "feed": "MyFeed",
    "location": "MyLocation",
    "other": "MyOther",
    "timestamp": "1486124533248000000"
 }
}
Wed May 17 08:36:45 UTC 2017 : Endpoint request URI: https://kinesis.eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/?Action=PutRecord
Wed May 17 08:36:45 UTC 2017 : Endpoint request headers: {Authorization=*******************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************0c8175, X-Amz-Date=20170517T083645Z, x-amzn-apigateway-api-id=aawfu1iss2, Accept=application/json, User-Agent=AmazonAPIGateway_aawfu1iss2, X-Amz-Security-Token=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 [TRUNCATED]
Wed May 17 08:36:45 UTC 2017 : Endpoint request body after transformations: {
    "Data": "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",
    "StreamName": "sensor-readings",
    "PartitionKey": "some-partition-key"
}
Wed May 17 08:36:45 UTC 2017 : Endpoint response body before transformations: {"SequenceNumber":"49572842939259722444903521585275507706013464929106919426","ShardId":"shardId-000000000000"}
Wed May 17 08:36:45 UTC 2017 : Endpoint response headers: {Server=Apache-Coyote/1.1, x-amzn-RequestId=c6c9329d-b519-d631-975f-3f401e1e34d2, x-amz-id-2=l5W9SQ3x4cnc3vF/oKlWoHK8qFsfRzZTK9byAK/Rpo477Of3JSlLPMorjH4/KV0s2BRKQtsVwbvYahkKKqfHtQZ5uHK6dKBs, Content-Length=110, Date=Wed, 17 May 2017 08:36:45 GMT, Content-Type=application/x-amz-json-1.1}
Wed May 17 08:36:45 UTC 2017 : Method response body after transformations: {"SequenceNumber":"49572842939259722444903521585275507706013464929106919426","ShardId":"shardId-000000000000"}
Wed May 17 08:36:45 UTC 2017 : Method response headers: {X-Amzn-Trace-Id=Root=1-591c0b9d-cf38868aada300b710e2ab3d, Content-Type=application/json}
Wed May 17 08:36:45 UTC 2017 : Successfully completed execution
Wed May 17 08:36:45 UTC 2017 : Method completed with status: 200
```

In there we have....

```
"Data": "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"
```

....which is the base64 encoded version of the payload being sent to Kinesis.

Can anyone tell me why I'm getting `data: 'e30='` in the Lambda or where I should start looking please?

Many thanks,

Luke.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your topology.
You connected API Gateway to Kinesis? that's weird to me, could you explain why?

Regarding your question - if you set up Kinesis as a trigger to your lambda then you can be sure that the lambda received the Kinesis record's content, the issue could be only between the API Gateway and Kinesis.

Comment: @johni - Thanks for the responnse.  

I'm using the API as a proxy to Kinesis (http://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/integrating-api-with-aws-services-kinesis.html). 

I agree in thinking that the problem is between the data going from API to Kinesis.  However, the response suggests all is OK going to Kinesis.

I'm very new to AWS so would be interested as to why you think that's "weird".

Comment: Regarding the "why" - because Kinesis streams is not something you would want to be public available to anyone who knows the API endpoint - I assume that is what you do by connection API Gateway to the stream.

If you still want your clients to be able to add records to your Kinesis stream, then you should connect your API Gateway to a new lambda, that makes the insertion to the Kinesis stream (Or have a service that does that, i.e. VMs with autoscale and so, will be much cheaper).

Basically - in terms of cost - you wouldn't want to use API Gateway and Lambda for _high volume_ topologies.

Comment: @johni - Correct, I do want clients to add records to the Kinesis stream via an API.  

I don't understand why I would put a new lambda in between API and Kinesis to push the data into the stream when I can do it "directly" via the Integration Request of API.  Isn't a lambda in between a different way to do the same thing?

The lambda I currently have triggered by the the stream (and isn't getting the data) will eventually push the data into a database.

Comment: try this:

`  (event.Records || []).forEach((record) => {
    const dataString = (new Buffer(record.kinesis.data,'base64').toString('utf8') || {});
`

Comment: Thanks @driedel - however every single time the lambda is hit the value at record.kinesis.data is always "e30=" which when decoded is "{}"

Comment: @Luke - if you Kinesis stream is publicly available - theoretically I could ruin your day by flooding it until it throttles (me and you).

With lambda in between, you could have managed throttling mechanisms with punishments to certain customers.

Comment: @Luke: is your kinesis stream situated in the same region than your lambda function? sometimes this messes up some functionality

Comment: @johni - You wouldn't do that to me would you johni?  We've only just met :) The Web API has authorization applied to it so only trusted users will be able to post to the stream.  Not that I know how to yet but I assumed that with the use of Usage Plans in Web API I could control/punish/charge users for overuse.

Comment: exactly: Usage Plans / API Keys should be the way to restrict access to your API and prevent customers from flooding your lambda or stream (in terms of costs - using lambda or kinesis doesn't make any difference)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, this is embarrassing...

Remember newbies - FIFO (First In First Out)

The first in was indeed an empty payload and until the lambda could handle that, subsequent data wasn't going to be processed.

I kept pushing new data on the the stream expecting it to be immediately handled.

I couldn't see the woods for the trees!

I hope this helps other newbies, or gives someone a laugh :)

Thanks @driedel - When I re-read your comment it made all made sense.